# how django render function handles for loop ，how parse a "if" or "for"

Tags: python, django

```
{% for name, age in data.items %}
Name: {{name}}, Age: {{age}} <br>
{% endfor %}
```

for loop in template,when render it,how does django know it is a for loop and show datas on html page.

I know how to use "for loop" in template, and render template&content in view function,but I dont understand how django interprets it.
How does the render function handle the for loop in html?I meand how implement it detailedly?

I just read souce code from render function jump to this point:\python3.8\Lib\string.py

[image]

for the self.pattern.sufunction just:

```
@overload
def sub(self, repl: AnyStr, string: AnyStr, count: int = ...) -> AnyStr: ...
```

so how does django implement it ?

Comment: You want to know how the Django template system works in detail? I suggest reading the documentation in full first https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/templates/. The section regarding advanced custom tags should give an idea of how the "block" tags could be implemented https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#parsing-until-another-block-tag

Comment: Thanks.I have read it but not fund the detail of how django implement it just how to use it.I try to write a web server ,return and render datas from databases or other interfaces now I know how to do it with vue.js